# key in assoc. array not accepted

Tags: javascript

I have to book (musical) notes in an assoc. array. The booking variable is:

```
var table = {
    "E": [],
    "F": [],
    "G": [],
    "A": [],
    "H": [],
    "c": [],
    "d": [],
    "e": [],
    "f": [],
    "g": [],
    "a": [],
    "h": [],
    "c'": [],
    "d'": [],
    "e'": [],
    "f'": [],
    "g'": [],
    "a'": [],
    "h'": [],
    "c\'\'": [],
    "d\'\'": []
};
```

When I parse my notes the values (note positions) are inserted without any problem. But when I would like to get the value, it's not possible to use the key `c'`, whereas e.g. `e`, `a`, `d` work. Why can `c'` accept values but can't be found as a key? Where must I look for an explanation?

Comment: It would be helpful to include the code where the issue actually occurs.

Answer (score 3):

How are you accessing that key?

```
table["c'"] = 'foo'; // work as expected
table.c' = 'foo'; // syntax error due to unterminated string
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an object property that is not a valid JavaScript identifier, make sure that you use bracket syntax `[…]`, like this:

```
console.log(table["c'"]); // works
```

**Further Reading**

- [Working with objects / Objects and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)